# Redis-cli not syncing with node

Tags: node.js, redis

Currently I have been doing some testing with my database by adding users.  I check the list of my users by displaying them in the web application and by using `HGETALL "players"` in `redis-cli` at command line.

It has come time for me to delete this key for a fresh production start.  Naturally I use the command `DEL "players"` in `redis-cli` and it returns successfull.  Checking the key again returns an empty result.

Awesome!

Checking in the web-app however, the same user list appears.  When I restart my the redis server, the users still appear.  Also, using `HGETALL "players"` also returns the same list of users I tested with.

How do I make `redis-cli` correspond to actually delete a key?

Thanks

Comment: are you caching in front of redis (or on the browser) - have you tried clearning your browser's cache

Comment: I have try reloading the browser without cache.  Strange thing is it loads up the old list in redis as well

Comment: just wondering - care you share your redis.conf file

Comment: Sure.  However, it is not in /etc/redis/redis.conf ..... you have any ideas?

Comment: You might want to verify you are connecting to the same redis server (host/IP and port). Did you install via OS package or manual? If manual look for re default config in the source directory.